# vis.js library is too big, how to get the part for timeline chart only

Tags: vis.js

vis.js library is 1.6mb and minified file is 610k which is still too big. It takes quite a long time to download the library file to users' machine, especially for slow network connection.

Currently I build timeline chart only by using this library, I am wondering if there is a way to get the part of the library for the timeline chart only.

Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 3):

As a alternative to building it yourself, there is a minified module that just contains the graph 2D and timeline modules, which is only 299KB. It is provided in the vis.js zip distribution as `vis-timeline-graph2d.min.js`.

That is available in CDNJS: https://cdnjs.com/libraries/vis if that matters to you.

Answer (score 0):

The existing visjs library bundled everything together. You want to include just the specific part you can follow the instructions [here](https://github.com/almende/vis#example-1-bundle-a-single-visualization). Instruction are pretty straight forward you should be able to build in no time.